# How to use cron jobs in observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cron, customer-account, magento-2.1.7

How to use Magento 2 cron jobs in observer file? I cannot get some values in cron file. Can anyone help me out how to configure cron in observer.

Comment: I don't get your question. A cron job is meant to be executed by the server, what do you want to achieve? Please be more precise with your question.

Comment: Have you created crontab.xml file in your module under etc folder?

Comment: I created cron function module and cron jobs working perfectly but can't get customer id using session in cron function